# Laravel 5: define new key with route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to define a custom `key` for more than 1 route, something like a route name, ex:

```
Route::GET('ww/popular/{page?}', array('uses'=>'WW@popular', 'as' => 'the_route_name'));
```

Retrieve route name:

```
Request::route()->getName(); //the_route_name
```

Is there a way to define a custom key like `cache` with value `true` or `false`

```
Route::GET('ww/popular/{page?}', array('uses'=>'WW@popular', 'cache' => true));
```

and retrieve the value ?

thx

Comment: Have you looked into using middleware parameters and adding whatever the parameter is to the request object and getting it back that way?

Comment: I dont believe you can add parameters like you suggested. I would have to agree with the previous comment and add custom parameters with middleware